# Spring Boot Connection with PostgreSql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have created a database in Postgres, which currently has no Tables

```
demographic=# \l
                                                               List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding | Locale Provider |      Collate       |       Ctype        | ICU Locale | ICU Rules |   Access privileges
-------------+----------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------
 demographic | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | English_India.1252 | English_India.1252 |            |           | =Tc/postgres         +
             |          |          |                 |                    |                    |            |           | postgres=CTc/postgres+
             |          |          |                 |                    |                    |            |           | khwab=CTc/postgres
 

demographic=# \d
Did not find any relations.
```

This is my application.properties...

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demographic
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*****

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I'll also provide pom.xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ehrc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mhms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mhms</name>
    <description>Demographics MHMS</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Finally this is my Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "id_proof", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
public class IdProofEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull(message = "Composer Id is required")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "id_number")
    private Number idNumber;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "issue_date")
    private Date issueDate;

    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    private Date expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "issuing_authority")
    private String issuingAuthority;

    @Column(name = "place_of_issue")
    private String placeOfIssue;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
}
```

This should create a new table that I specified with `@Table` annotation in my entity, right? But upon executing the project I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : id_proof
```

Can someone help me out here?

I crossed check user config and password, they are correct, as it is connecting to the database.

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace instead of a random half snippet from it.

Comment: You should also include (the relevant part of) the entity itself, and any relevant logging from JPA trying to initialize your database.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please check once again? I have added the relevant information needed. 
Thank you for the inputs, I am just starting out here, still new to asking question.

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but still worth writing :) You approach is called "Code First". Please consider using "Database First". Code First is usually good only for school examples with very simple databases. In the real production applications it brings more problems than benefits.

Comment: Kindly add POM file and describe the version of Java and hibernate in your question.

Comment: The full stacktrace is still relevant. However I doubt that using `BigInteger` as a type for the `@Id` would work. Use an `Integer` or probably a `Long` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  @NotNull(message = "Composer Id is required")
  private BigInteger id;
```

you are using `BigInteger` as a type for primary key what is wrong.

Just change to `Long` it is going to fix your problem

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  @NotNull(message = "Composer Id is required")
  private Long id;
```

For you to know: `BIGINT` is the same as a Java Long, not a `BigInteger`

Comment: Heyy, thank you for answering. I created the table with psql queries and did change BigInteger to Long, in entity, dto and wherever required. It is working now. Thanks again for the input.

Comment: If it was helpfully don’t forget to accept answer and upvote it for future if someone will have the same problem